# Use a Standard Serial Dispatch Queues in C++?

Tags: c++, task-queue

I want to write a toy app that will start with 1 instance and grow until it hits 5fps. The instance have a run() method that should take <1ms to run. So instead of actual threads i'd like to use a serial dispatch queue to take task and execute them. I have a multicore machine and i would not like locking if i could avoid it. I dont want to write a serial dispatch queue but is there a C++(0x?) standard serial dispatch queue i can use?

The task may add themselves back in or the queue could just loop between each element. It doesnt matter to me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a standard queue, but without locking, then look for a lock-free queue implementation.  There is no standard lock-free queue in C++11.

Instead of a single queue, why not use a vector of tasks per core/thread and cycle between them?  For example, if you have 4 CPU and threads, have a vector of tasks for each one.  Distribute the tasks equally between them and then just iterate over them as you mention in your looping comment in the last sentence.  That'd have no locking and would have the same processing order guarantees (i.e. none) that a queue from multiple threads would have.